# Differential equations: Of non-vertical lines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the differential equation of all non-vertical lines in a plane.

I am not sure how to solve this problem. To do that I have to create an equation. 

I am not able do so.

Is it $x \ne 0 $ ?

Please offer your assistance

Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of any non-vertical line in the plane is $y = ax + b$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, the differential equation will be $y' = a$, for all $a$.

EDIT: I let this slip by, we can in fact have $a$ as zero. As **Mathguy** pointed out, this means all horizontal lines. Sorry.

Comment: Why cant a vertial line be y=ax+b?

Comment: Is the edit correct?

Comment: Why can't $a=0$ ? It simply implies the line is horizontal.

Comment: @Mathguy: You are absolutely right, I don't know what I was thinking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The line is vertical when $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = 0.$
Thus, for all non vertical lines:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = a$$
where, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \neq 0.$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know what I was thinking.